# How to write a research paper properly

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, linear-algebra

I'm a student, 15yrs, in 10th standard. I live in India. I want to become a pure mathematician or a Theoretical Physicist. I want to know what is the correct protocol to write a research papers in physics and mathematics. Obviously a physics paper won't be identical to a mathematics paper. What are the differences? I am doing linear algebra and multivariable calculus to better understand quantum physics. And number theory in math.

Comment: Kind of a broad question. Not sure if this is the correct forum for it.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Which forum should I post it in?

Comment: @user167920 as a person 3 years elder to you, let me tell you that by the time you write a paper, you'll know how to write it, and your guide will surely help you. Currently, you look forward to gaining huge knowledge rather than exam marks, the latter of which is insignificant in life. Also, this question is off-topic in this site.

Comment: @WrichikBasu guessing from your name, you also studied in India, do the boards marks really not matter?

Comment: @user167920 yes, I know that it will matter in the beginning, and being in class X, you are having to study those history and geography as well. True, boards do matter, but I'll recommend you to study well and not care abut marks. Just rectify your errors. Don't participate in the rat race of jealousy. Keep life simple.

Comment: The first real paper will be better written if the author has first written some practice papers for their own interest or as school assignments. Yes, you will have an advisor when you get to the real thing, but don't let that stop you from trying to practice now.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is too broad to be addressed properly.

Comment: In addition to being much too broad, this is off topic here. More specific questions about how to write papers may be appropriate in [chat] or _perhaps_ at [academia.SE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by reading a lot of papers in the fields you're interested in. Keep notes with citations. I like to use LaTeX/bibtex to keep track of references. Those notes will help you plan your research and also can be rearranged into a properly referenced background/introduction for a paper when you have some original research to publish.

Before that, it may help to write a practice review paper and submit it to your teacher to review or hire a grad student as a tutor to help with edits. If you participate in a science fair, you can write up your project as if it is a journal paper regardless of whether you think you have actually done publishable work---if not, just share it with your school.

When you begin research at a university, you will have an advisor who will help you edit your papers or delegate part of the task to a more senior grad student or post doc.